# Accessing a DropDownList from a DetailsView in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, detailsview

I have a `DetailsView` called DetailsView1 as follows with a `DropDownList` called SupplierDD and a `CheckBox` called ApprovedCB.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1 " runat="server" Width="70%" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="DetailsViewDS " 
             DefaultMode="Edit">
            <Fields>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supplier">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="SupplierDD"/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved" SortExpression="ApprovedForOrderFromSupplier">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ApprovedCB" OnClick="return CheckIfSupplierIsSelected(this);" Checked='<%# Bind("ApprovedForOrderFromSupplier") %> />
..................
```

I have JavaScript code as following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckIfSupplierIsSelected(cb) {
        var detailsView = document.getElementById('<%= DetailsView1.ClientID %>');       
        var supplierDD1 = detailsView.getElementById('<%= SupplierDD.ClientID %>');
        //var supplierDD2 = detailsView.child.getElementById('<%= SupplierDD.ClientID %>'); //have tried this way too
        if (cb.checked === true) {
            alert("checked");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("unchecked");
            return true;
        }
   }
</script>
```

The error I am getting is the name SupplierDD does not exist in the current context. Can anyone help me know how to declare the new SupplierDD in the JavaScript. I have tried several ways, as you can see below in the JavaScript to get the SupplierDD. I obviously have no problem with the `Checkbox` as it is passed with the JavaScript method call in the `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the following line -

```
var supplierDD1 = detailsView.getElementById('<%= SupplierDD.ClientID %>');
```

Try using jQuery find selector like -

```
var supChk = detailsView.find('<%= SupplierDD.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and still have the same error.